# Angular: two different modules or single module

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular5, angular4-router

I recently started working on Angular (`Angular5`). My application has tabs named `Home, School, Office` and I have two types of users `Admin` and `non-admin`. As soon as the `Office` tab is clicked Admin page will be redirected to Admin page and non-admin user will be redirected to non-admin page.

So, for this requirement do I need to make two different modules? OR shall I make a single module and redirect on the bases of user types? Please guide me with the project structure.

Comment: Easy: if you're not sure if you need multiple modules, you don't need multiple modules.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25820677/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-multiple-modules-in-angular. Multiple modules could be useful for separating admin part of application from non-admin part.

Comment: The purpose of a ngModule is to group components together, it has nothing to do with admin or non-admin user rights. What you should do to solve your problem: use a token and route guard.

Comment: You should lazy load something when you are sure that, in this case, admin & non-admin use different components and services. You can create third module where you put the `shared` components and services.

Comment: It depends on how many differences there are in the view if there are common components may be its better using a structural directive

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to **2 different modules** as they are both a separate feature and Lazy Load them on your parent route *(e.g AppRouting or others)*.
Supposedly, on your **Admin** it has features that the **Non-Admin** doesn't have and they both have different roles in your application. So you should separate them based on their feature.

> **Feature Module**
>
> - create multiple feature modules for every independent feature of the application
> - help you partition the app into focused areas
> - Keep code related to a specific functionality or feature separate from other code
>
> https://angular.io/guide/feature-modules#feature-modules-vs-root-modules

For your case, your feature modules are your **/admin** and **/non-admin** *(or any terms you used on your directory)*. Under those are its components, services, routing and ngModule.

Answer (score 1):

Modules are not separated by roles of your application - Separation of modules is the process of separating your code based on no complexity if in case you have a `component` that need to be used in multiple places you can move that component to a `shared` module and `import` that module into all your sub modules - if you want to load a module Lazily you can work on loading a module Lazily

In your case - the word is `route` for you - you can check whether the user has `admin` or `non-admin` while routing, that can be achieved by using `Resolver` which does magic for you - check this [link](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-guard) for further queries

Try something like this

**Router**

```
{
    path: 'pathName',
    component: ComponentName,
    resolve: { RolePermission: RolePermissionService },
}
```

**RolePermissionService**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RolePermissionService implements Resolve<object | string> {

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | string> | Promise<boolean | string>  {
        return new Promise(resolve => {

             return resolve(true);

            // Your logic here - Call the service to check whether admin or non-admin
            // Bind the data in your route or you can navigate from here
        });
    }
}
```

So the return data will bind to the `RolePermission` object in your route and finally you can read it in your `component`

**Component**

In you component you can read that data like this

`this._activatedRoute.snapshot.data["RolePermission"].ISSubmitSlotRequest;`

So this will solve your problem you can map this service to all the routes you want and you can get the role of the user - I'm not against module creation this will be a better way to read the roles on routing - check that link for more idea - Happy coding :)