# Angular: routing to different modules on page load

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-router

I recently started working on Angular (Angular 5), routing being very new and but weak. My application has 3 tabs named `Home, School, Office` and I have two types of users `Admin` and `non-admin`. As soon as the `Office` tab is clicked Admin will be redirected to Admin page and non-admin user will be redirected to non-admin page.

So, for this requirement I did routing like this:

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AdminModule,
    NonAdminModule
  ],
  declarations: [AppComnonent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(){
 this.userIsAdmin = true;
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div *ngIf='!userIsAdmin '>
<non-admin-page></non-admin-page>
</div>
<div *ngIf='userIsAdmin '>
<admin-page></admin-page>
</div>
```

non-admin.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
      imports: [

      ],
      declarations: [NonAdminComnonent],
      exports: [NonAdminComnonent]
    })
    export class NonAdminPageModule { }
```

admin.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
      imports: [

      ],
      declarations: [AdminComnonent],
      exports: [AdminComponent]
    })
    export class AdminPageModule { }
```

admin-page.html

```
<div>I am ADMIN</div>
```

non-admin-page.html

```
<div>I am not an ADMIN</div>
```

I have to route to different modules on page load, is my routing correct? Please guide me.

Comment: why you are bootrap the AdminComponent from AdminPageModule, alredy your AppCmponent is bootstraped

Comment: Ohhh, that was a typo. Corrected it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular: two different modules or single module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53516301/angular-two-different-modules-or-single-module)

Answer (score 0):

I would use lazy loading: [How to Route to Feature Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49621578/how-to-route-to-feature-module/49622371#49622371).

If not try this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hd7ayj.

Instead of disney, your code would be school.

See my profile to see the actual app.

Hope this helps. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you are just showing the **admin** and **non-admin** html based on condition in the same component.
If you want to use routing to differentiate, you could use below procedure,

1. Create a flag to differentiate the User (as you have already done)
2. Create tabs based on this condition. Have two tab items for office - one which routes to **admin** and other which routes to **non-admin** and show only one of these based on the flag.

This way you can differentiate the components for admin and non-admin.

Comment: This will be a requirement change and I cannot change the requirement. I can only have 1 tab, have to work with it only

Comment: In that case, you can use resolve routing. When you try to route to office tab, you can handle the conditions and based on that you can proceed with routing(to admin component) or redirect to a different route(non-admin component). You can find example for the same here: https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-resolve-guard-example